# Is there an equivalent for AnyDVD on Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, dvd, ripping, bsd

What would be the equivalent to AnyDVD on Unix (linux,*bsd etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [K9Copy](http://k9copy.sourceforge.net/)
- [AcidRip](http://untrepid.com/acidrip/)
- [dvd::rip](http://www.exit1.org/dvdrip/)

Comment: not quite the same, but since noone else answered and this is pretty close ...